# Xrm.Utility.openwebresource opens new tab

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

We have an onprem crm 2016. I'm opening an html webresource on a click of a ribbon button. I'm using `Xrm.Utility.openWebResource(...)`. The problem with that is we're using IE11 and all users' browsers are configured to let IE decide how to open pop ups.

Guess what, IE decides to open a new tab! Is there a way to open an html web resource in a new window without changing the users' browser options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Xrm.Utility.openWebResource()` performs different in Chrome compared to IE11. Below options are there, pick it what suits you.

1. `window.open()`
2. Unsupported way to open modal dialog - `showModalDialog`
3. `Xrm.Internal.openDialog()`

[Source](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/185488)

`Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm()` has an option to mention as `openInNewWindow = true` in parameter `windowOptions` which is not available for `openWebResource()`

Comment: I just saw your response @Arun. I ended up using window.open, but keep in mind this probably not gonna work with mobile client. Thanks