# How to open a web resource in a new tab instead of a new window when clicking a ribbon button

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, ribbon, dynamics-365

I've created a ribbon button inside my Dynamics 365 crm. 
On click, the ribbon Button should open a new tab with some stuff in it.

**The problem:**

This is the code launched when its clicked:

```
function OpenPage () 
{
     Xrm.Utility.openWebResource("new_someWebResourceHTML");
}
```

the code actually works, and it works well, it opens a new window new_someWebResourceHTML.html.

**The question:**

Is there some way to open a web resource on a new tab, instead of a new window, using javascript?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: Refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122716/xrm-utility-openwebresource-opens-new-tab

Answer (score 1):

Use window.open with second parameter '_blank':

```
function openInNewTab(webResource) {
  var prefixUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUri() + '/WebResources/'
  var win = window.open(prefixUrl + webResource +, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```